# File browse and open dialogs not working(opening) on AIR Windows

Tags: windows, actionscript-3, air

[image]We have many customers using our AIR application on Mac and Windows, but one customer has this issue, no File popup dialogs, for opening, browse open, this are open from button click handlers but we are on AIR not on Flash in browser so there should not be restrictions, I am unable to find on google similar issues and I am not sure what could cause this only on this machine and how to fix it(if I could fix it in code or tell customer what to configure) 
EDIT, here is some sample code

```
var browseFile:File = File.documentsDirectory;
browseFile.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, fileSelected);
browseFile.browseForDirectory("Select Local Folder");
```

EDIT2
This is the exception
Error: Error #2014: Feature is not available at this time.
    at flash.filesystem::File$/initDocumentsDir()
    at flash.filesystem::File$/get documentsDirectoryPath()
    at flash.filesystem::File$/get documentsDirectory()

My problem is that I use a .swc that also uses this code that I don't have the source to work around this. I was not aware that this functionality could not work

Comment: Can you post some code ?

Comment: @AdrianPirvulescu I posted a sample

Comment: Is there any specific antivirus software installed at the customer, Also I suggest you to listen for ioError and securityError and display some sort of Alert message. I previously had problems with an old version of Avast which was flagging my Air apps as visures :D

Comment: If you throw a trace right before that code snippet, does it actually trace to your console? My only guess is that you are not actually hitting this code. Nothing else should be stopping it from working that I know of

Comment: @AdrianPirvulescu I found more info, see the edits

Comment: how do you compile your swc. ? flash builder ? If yes then you nees to check  "Include Adobe AIR libraries" inside Project->Properties->Flex library Compiler, for your flex library project.

Comment: @AdrianPirvulescu there is not a compile issue, this app works on many system, is an issue with this windows setup

Comment: Sorry Simion, I cannot imagine what could be wrong with the code. I can only assume this is a local issue with the client setup and should not make the object of future investigation from your side. It can be to antivirus, user rights and so on... I suggest you check what is different with this particular client

Comment: @AdrianPirvulescu yeah, my work around was to search all my code for File.documentsDirectory and replace it with a custom function that will return other directory in appdata if the documents dir can't be accessed,  the problem is that other code(like the app updater uses the File.documentsDirectory and I can't patch